# Property 'config' does not exist on type 'typeof "amazon-cognito-identity-js"'?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

In my Ionic3 application I want to update the cognito `config.region` and `config.credentials` but I'm getting the following error **Property 'config' does not exist on type 'typeof "amazon-cognito-identity-js"' ??**

```
AWSCognito.config.region  = 'us-east-1';

AWSCognito.config.credentials = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  // This will be the Pool Id from your Cognito user pool.
  IdentityPoolId: ConstantsValues.IdentityPoolId
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How you (should) reference this config object is dependent on how you're bringing in Amazon's code.  Without seeing thee `import`, `require`, or `<script>` that you're using to do so, it's hard to say exactly what is off.

From [Amazon's documentation](https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-identity-js/) on `amazon-cognito-identity-js`:

> Note that the Amazon Cognito AWS SDK for JavaScript is just a slimmed
>   down version of the AWS Javascript SDK namespaced as AWSCognito
>   instead of AWS. It references only the Amazon Cognito Identity
>   service.

I'm accustomed an approach like this, using the full SDK:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
```

Then you can do things like this through the `AWS` namespace:

```
AWS.config.credentials.clearCachedId();
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
var cognitosync = new AWS.CognitoSync();
```

I'm also familiar with this approach using `amazon-cognito-identity-js`, as so:

```
import * as Cognito from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
```

which allows this type of access:

```
return new Cognito.CognitoUser({
    Username: this.toUsername(email),
    Pool: this.props.appState.state.pool
});

getAuthTokenFromCognitoUserPool = (): Promise<Cognito.CognitoIdToken> => {
...
}
```

However, using the imports above, there is no `Cognito.config` object, only an `AWS.config` object.

I'd suggest you try importing the full SDK, if you're not already, and go through the `AWS` namespace.  If you're using script tags, that might look something like this:

```
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.133.0.min.js"></script>
```

If you already have a tag like this, you might just need to change `AWSCognito.config` to `AWS.config`.

Hope this helps; happy hacking!

Answer (score 1):

Just import amazon-sdk into your service.

```
import * as AWS from "aws-sdk";
```

Then you can set a region.

```
AWS.config.region  = 'us-east-1';
```